How to extract text from a span tag that also have an inner span
I have a html below:
<span class="ui-cfs-sn-l" xpath="1">
    ABC
    <span class="ui-cfs-txt">°⌃</span>
</span>

I used the following python code to extract the text which returns ABC°⌃
element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//span[@class='ui-cfs-sn-l']")
result = element.text

Is there a way to extract just the text before the inner span? The solution should return ABC

You can extract the text like this:
result = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('ui-cfs-sn-l')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue")

or:
element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//span[@class='ui-cfs-sn-l']")
result = element.get_attribute('innerHTML').split('<')[0].strip()  # make sure no '<' is in your target text

or:
element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//span[@class='ui-cfs-sn-l']")
result = element.get_attribute('textContent').strip().split('\n')[0] # make sure no '\n' is in your target text


Thanks @vassiliev. Will try out the 2nd option splitting by delmiter '<span'.

Just to add, some of the text contain ampersand character "&" so innerHTML extract it as "&".
I had to use html2text library to convert html string back to normal string and  .strip() to remove newline characters from the html string.

@Jason how about this:  import html;html.unescape("&amp;")

You could use Pythons BeautifulSoup4 library to achieve this.

Beautiful Soup is a library that makes it easy to scrape information from web pages. It sits atop an HTML or XML parser, providing Pythonic idioms for iterating, searching, and modifying the parse tree.

Here is an example:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = '<span class="ui-cfs-sn-l" xpath="1">ABC<span class="ui-cfs-txt">°⌃</span></span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, features='html.parser')

desired_content = soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'ui-cfs-sn-l'})[0].contents[0]
print(desired_content)  # outputs 'ABC'

Edit:
You can use BeautifulSoup with Selenium as described in this answer

Assuming you are on the page you want to parse, Selenium stores the source HTML in the driver's page_source attribute. You would then load the page_source into BeautifulSoup as follows:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://yoursite.com')
html_content = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, features='html.parser')
desired_content = soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'ui-cfs-sn-l'})[0].contents[0]
print(desired_content)


I'm using Python Selenium, is there solution without using BeautifulSoup?
